# Show that Airy function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, dispersive-pde

I want to establish the bounds for the Airy function
\begin{equation}
K(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi.
\end{equation}
I want to show that $K(x)=O_N(<x>^{-N})$ for any $N\geq0$ and $x>0$; and $K(x)=O(<x>^{-1/4})$ for $x\leq0$, where
\begin{equation}
<x>=(1+x^2)^{1/2}.
\end{equation}

I was told to consider 3 cases:

- When $x\geq 1$, use repeated integration by parts.
- When $-1<x<1$, use Van der Corput Lemma.
- When $x\leq-1$, split the integral into pieces and use Van der Corput Lemma, or integration by parts on each piece.

My attempt:

When $x\geq1$,
\begin{equation}
K(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{i(x+3\xi^2)} i(x+3\xi^2) e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \frac{-1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \partial_\xi\left( \frac{1}{i(x+3\xi^2)} \right) e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi
= \frac{-1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{6i\xi}{(x+3\xi^2)^2} e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \partial_\xi\left( \frac{1}{i(x+3\xi^2)} \frac{6i\xi}{(x+3\xi^2)^2} \right) e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \partial_\xi\left( \frac{6\xi}{(x+3\xi^2)^3} \right) e^{i(x\xi+\xi^3)} \,d\xi.
\end{equation}
I don't see how this turns out to the desired bound $O_N(<x>^{-N})$.

When $-1<x<1$, how can I apply the Lemma? I need a compact interval $I$ for $\xi$. Should I use
\begin{equation}
\int_I e^{i\phi(\xi)} \,d\xi \qquad or \qquad \int_I e^{i\phi(\xi)}\Psi(\xi) \,d\xi\:?
\end{equation}
What should I choose $\phi$?

When $x\leq-1$, I don't see how to split up the integral. I don't see how the value of $x$ can affect the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: Asymptotics for Airy functions are explained in great detail from page $8$ to page $14$ [here](math.arizona.edu/~meissen/docs/asymptotics.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there anyway to do the problem by the provided hints?